# Getting started with Bleve using BoltDB

Tags: go, boltdb, bleve

I am trying to wrap my head around Bleve and I understand everything that is going on in the tutorials, videos and documentation. I however get very confused when I am using it on BoltDB and don't know how to start.

Say I have an existing BoltDB database called `data.db` populated with values of struct type Person

```
type Person struct {
   ID int          `json:"id"`             
   Name string     `json:"name"` 
   Age int         `json:"age"`
   Sex string      `json:"sex"`
}
```

How do I index this data so that I can do a search? How do I handle the indexing of data that will be stored in the database in the future?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Bleve appears to use BoltDB to store its own indexes (rather than building them from an existing Bolt database): https://godoc.org/github.com/blevesearch/bleve/index/store/boltdb

Comment: Further: what are you building with BoltDB? It's an excellent KV store for things like auth sessions, tokens, etc but is not suited to ad-hoc queries or full text search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bleve uses BoltDB as one of several backend stores and is separate from where you store your application data. To index your data in Bleve, simply add your `Index`:

`index.Index(person.ID, person)`

That `index` exists separately from your application data (whether it's in Bolt, Postgres, etc).

To retrieve your data, you'll need to construct a search request using `bleve.NewSearchRequest()`, then call `Index.Search()`. This will return a `SearchResult` which includes a `Hits` field where you can retrieve the `ID` for your object. You can use this to look up the object in your application data store.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of BoltDB.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do understand, from the documentation, how data is being indexed and how searches are being done. I however still do not understand how the actual data from BoltDB is being employed here.

Comment: Bleve uses a BoltDB store for its own internal format of the indexed data. It's better to think of Bleve as a black box. Your BoltDB store doesn't interact with it except through the Bleve API.

Answer (score 2):

How you index your data depends on how you want to query for it.

If you want to query by any arbitrary fields, like {Age:15, Name:"Bob"} then BoltDB isn't an awesome fit for your problem.

BoltDB is simply a key value store with fast access to sequential keys and efficient prefix seeking.  It's not really a replacement for general use databases.

You likely want something more like a document store (ie: MongoDB) or RDBMS (ie: PostgreSQL).

If you just wanted something that uses simple files and is embedded, you could also use [SQlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) with the [Go module](http://mattn.github.io/go-sqlite3/)

If you want to search by only a single field, like ID or Name, then use that as the key.

If lookup speed doesn't matter at all, I guess you can use Bolt to just iterate over the entire db, parse the json and check the fields.  But that's probably the worst approach you could take.

Comment: I find Bolt works great as an application data store when paired with a search index. For many applications, data retrieval occurs either through primary key or full text search. Key/value stores perform great at primary key search and your FTE index works great for full text search.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you reply. It however doesn't answer my question :(

Comment: Yep, both of y'all are right.  I didn't really dig enough in to the topic.